# Airflow - execute X dynamic tasks with max 4 tasks in parallel

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

As a step one in my dag, i am trying to get a list of items from some source, say **idList** with count of say 100.

Is it possible in Airflow to process all the 100 items in **idList**, with a task concurrency of 4 maximum? (4 at a time) After one task is complete, it should pick up the next **id** from the **idList** and create task dynamically to process it.

I have tried the [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) but it doesn't seem to have a max parallelization/concurrency factor associated with it for the specific DAG Run.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible, I just created an [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/29084) to propose the feature, and I will try to submit a PR this weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Airflow 2.6, we introduced a new parameter `max_active_tis_per_dagrun` to control the mapped task concurrency in the same DAG run.

Here is an example:

```py
import pendulum
import time

from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(
    dag_id='max_active_tis_per_dagrun',
    default_args={},
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"),
    schedule=None
)
def processing_dag():

    @task
    def get_numbers():
        return list(range(20))

    @task(max_active_tis_per_dagrun=2)
    def process(number):
        print(number)
        time.sleep(5)

    numbers = get_numbers()

    process.expand(number=numbers)


my_dag = processing_dag()
```

You can trigger 4 DAG runs via the UI, and check how many mapped task will be running in parallel in each DAG run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pools to limit parallelism. Configure the name of a pool on the mapped task (e.g. `pool="max_2"`), for example:

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(dag_id="dynamic_task_mapping_with_pool", start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule_interval=None):

    @task
    def list_files():
        return list(range(10))

    @task(pool="max_2")
    def process_files(file):
        print(f"Do something with {file}")
        time.sleep(5)

    process_files.expand(file=list_files())
```

With a pool of size 2, you'll see the mapped instances progress in batches of 2 instances:

[image]
[image]

Comment: The pool `max_2` is used in all the dag runs, which is similar of using `max_active_tis_per_dag` to limit the number of parallel ti in all the dag runs of the dag. I don't think this is what he is looking for.

Comment: Right, I need to have this limit per DAG Run. There can be many instances of DAG Runs, but I need a max of 4 per running instance of the DAG.

Comment: That seems oddly specific, what's the use case for that? Parallelism is typically limited for resource consumption, but with a per-instance limit, you can technically still have an unlimited number of instances running.